# Run Celery task on same server that handled Flask request

Tags: python, flask, celery, distributed-computing

I have a setup with multiple servers running both my Flask app and Celery workers.  A Flask route handles a file upload locally and queues a Celery task to upload that file to a CDN.

The Celery task could be handled by any node in the cluster.  If the Celery task is handled by a different node than the one that handled the Flask route, the file will not be found and the task will fail.

How can I ensure that the Celery task runs on the same node that handled the the Flask route?

Answer (score 3):

If you want the server that handled the upload to handle the background job, then you don't need Celery at all.  Celery is good when you need to distribute and queue tasks, but what you describe is local and immediately subsequent to the upload.

Instead of a Celery task, just spawn a process locally to handle the background job.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        Process(target=handle_file, args=(f,)).start()
        return redirect(request.path)

    return render_template('upload.html')

def handle_file(f):
    print(f.read())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('localhost')
```

---

If you want to stick with Celery, you could forgoe saving the file locally and pass the file data as an argument to the task, so no matter what server handled the upload, the one that handled the task would always have the data.  There may be performance issues if the file is large though.

```
@celery.task
def upload(data):
    ...

upload.delay(file.read())
```